# Subir varias imágenes a un servidor

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web en la que mi idea es subir varias imágenes mediante `input type="file" multiple`. El problema acá es que en realidad no se como puede ser esto sin poner varios `input type="file"`

Este es el código con el que le asigno el nombre y la ubicación a la imagen pero esto sólo es para una:

```
string ruta = Request.MapPath("Imagenes/");
        Random r = new Random();
        int numero = r.Next(5, 10000000);
        nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace(" ", "_");
        if (Directory.Exists(ruta) == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ruta);
        string archivo = Path.GetFileName(urlImg.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(archivo);
        archivo = archivo.Substring(archivo.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).ToLower();
        archivo = "Imagen_" + numero + extension;
        urlImg.SaveAs(ruta + archivo);
        string urlImgen = "/Page/Imagenes/" + archivo;
        nombreBanner = nombreBanner.Replace("_", " ");
```

Alguien tiene una idea para subir varias imágenes, lo estoy desarrollando con c# y sql server. 
Si me pudieran ayudar u orientar se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu problema, estás intentando subir varias imágenes a una ruta física en un servidor o intentas guardar la ruta de las imágenes en una base de datos sql server?

Comment: Si lo siento, creo que no me explique correctamente. Las imágenes las guardo en un servidor y lo que guardo en la base de datos es la ruta donde están almacenadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno puedes usar algo como esto:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase archivo = Request.Files[i];
    if(archivo.ContentLength >0){

       ruta = Request.MapPath("Imagenes/");
       Random r = new Random();
       int numero = r.Next(5, 10000000);
       urlImg.SaveAs(ruta + archivo);

    }
}
```

Comment: gracias, lo intentare hacer como dices :D

Answer (score 1):

Deberias recorrer todas las imagenes que enviaste ya que no es un solo file, si no que puede ser 1 o muchos mas

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
    if(file.ContentLength >0){
    //Y aqui dentro de codigo

}
```

Comment: gracias, lo intentare hacer así :D